# Custom template language for Django

Tags: django, django-templates, haml

I want using a different templating language with Django. It's actually [HamlPy](https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy), which is a HAML-inspired language, that directly translates to Django templates.
Thus, I can do something like

```
from hamlpy import Compiler
compiler = Compiler()
django_template_string = compiler.process(hamlpy_template_string)
```

Please notice, it doesn't need any context - it's just *template text* preprocessing. The resultant text can than be used as a Django template in a normal way.

So, I want to wrap this code inside some deus-ex-machina code that will gracefully intervent template loading and preprocess it before Django tries to render or even parse it.

From what I see, if I could overload the `Parser` class and do

```
def parse(str):
    str = preprocess(str)
    super().parse(str)
```

it would be the most transparent solution.

I know about custom tags and filters. I realize that my task can be solved with the "global" `preprocess_hamlpy' tag.

But I wonder if it can be done in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Write a template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates) and put it in your settings.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, but limits the users to juts one type of template loading (or requires multiple identical copies). Is this the recommended way?

Comment: I mean, I can inherit from FSLoader and preprocess the file after it's found, but then I will need duplicating it for AppDirsLoader

Comment: You could write a loader that encapsulates both.

Comment: ah, makes sense. I suppose I can even parse TEMPLATE_LOADERS on my own and run all those above HamlpyLoader, until they find the template. Thank you

Comment: actually I found djaml, that does exactly this